# grails controller handling ajax file upload

Tags: grails

I am implementing a file uplaod via jquery ajax but I fail to do something with the data on the controller side. I get the params but not the File which is in this example a jpeg. The data is in the Request Payload.

[image: Chrome output]

My problem is on server side. How do I get a File on server side?

```
@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_PARTNER', 'ROLE_READ_ONLY',     'ROLE_USER_PAYING'])
def fileupload () {
    println "---------------------------------------------------"
    params.each{
        println it.key +"="+ it.value
    }
    request.getHeaderNames().each{
        println (it)
    }

    render("OK")
}
```

This is the output i receive:

```
---------------------------------------------------
filename=1506368_10152113826431683_327028558_o.jpg
apiKey=c7937acaf6d5411d8920d194dc48c041
action=fileupload
controller=post
host
connection
content-length
...
```

How do I get the file in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same, and using `request.getInputStream()` in the controller for getting the binary data. This actually comes from the `ServletRequest` interface - see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--